# What are good out of the box alternative geocoding solutions to Esri's services?

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-online

Esri's **[legacy geocoding services](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/28/2nd-reminder-legacy-geocoding-and-routing-services-will-be-retired-on-december-31-2013/)** will retire at the end of the year, what are good GIS services that can replace the North American and US Streets geocoders?

I have totally excluded Esri's replacement, the **[ArcGIS Online Geocoding Service](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/index.html)** as it is a subscription service.

Comment: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/28/2nd-reminder-legacy-geocoding-and-routing-services-will-be-retired-on-december-31-2013/

Comment: A simple US Streets geocoder, ideally open and that can be leveraged in ArcGIS as a GIS Service.

Comment: Are you specifically against the topic of commercial/pay-to-play services?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ESRI services, but can suggest Nominatim.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

Los Angeles County EGIS has developed a nationwider locator.
http://gis.lacounty.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/CAMS_Locator_Nationwide/GeocodeServer